# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created my project at https://start.spring.io/, when executing it this error appeared

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.2:run
> (default-cli) on project

Here are my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${parent.version}</version>                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Locally, on my machine I have

Apache Maven 3.9.6

Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.6-bin\apache-maven-3.9.6

Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21

Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8

OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

> I found similar questions on the internet, but I didn't find any
> solutions. I have similar problems when I try to start any other
> project.

Answer (score 0):

in order to run the spring boot in your local with mvn command please use command below

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run
```

and the pom has

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

that does not look right, if you check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#java-17-baseline-and-java-19-support)

> Spring Boot 3.0 requires Java 17 as a minimum version

better delete that plugin from pom, it should have been managed by the parent anyway.